# ionic2: Uploading source images to prepare for transformations failed?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using `ionic2`, I want to set custom splash image so I set `splash.png` in `../myproject/resources/splash.png` and then i run this command: `ionic cordova resources --splash` but I got this error:

```
Error: socket hang up
at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1140:19)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was the internet connection speed is low